# cant start bundle on apache felix

Tags: java, frameworks, osgi, apache-felix

I am trying to start my OSGi bundle with apache felix but probably i am doing something wrong.
The error i am getting is :

g! install file:/c:/classes/example.jar                                                                         16:28:37
Bundle ID: 76
g! start 76                                                                                                     16:28:58
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tutorial.example1.Activator not found by tutorial.example1 [76]

And this is my code

package tutorial.example1;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

```
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Bundle started");
}

public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Bundle stopped");
}
```

}

Manifest-Version: 1.0

Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2

Bundle-Name: Example Bundle

Bundle-SymbolicName: tutorial.example1

Bundle-Version: 1.10.0
Bundle-Activator: tutorial.example1.Activator
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework